# Wix installer when stopped while upgrading, partly installs the new version

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

I created an EXE using burn bootstrapper which consists of 3 MSIs. I expect my installer to revert to previous version when process is terminated while upgrading. Therefore I specified the Schedule to be "afterInstallExecute" according to what I have read as below :

[image]

[image]

so this is how my major upgrade element looks like in all of the MSIs.

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." Schedule="afterInstallExecute"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I expect the installer to rollback during termination of the process and bring back the old version. Also how will this apply to the EXE? Please advice.

Comment: Terminated as in you forcibly kill the process through task manager?

Comment: Rollback applies internally to the MSI while it is doing the install, the install transaction. It doesn't uninstall just because the bootstrapper dies. Burn has RollbackBoundary, but it can't do anything if it's crashed.

Comment: @BrianSutherland yes.

Comment: @PhilDW then during which occasions would it do what I've expected here?